# # (number sign) and * (asterisk) in German

Tags: single-word-request, punctuation

I was on the phone today with a German. But I couldn't find the name of these in German:

## `#` `*`

I tried to find out with Google but I haven't found. Could someone tell me what they are called?

Comment: Tip: you could search for an article in the english Wikipedia and then switch to the article in another language on the left hand side: Menu entry `Languages`.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that [`Doppelkreuz`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelkreuz_%28Schriftzeichen%29) is the official German name for `#`. Most people will probably use `Raute` or `Rautenzeichen` instead though.

The name of `*` is as before mentioned [`Stern`, `Sternchen` or `Asterisk`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sternchen_%28Schriftzeichen%29).

Taken from Wikipedia:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> **#** = **Oktothorp** (offiziell) oder **Rautenzeichen**
>   ***** = **Asterisk** (offiziell) oder **Sternchen**

Die offiziellen Benennungen sind nicht so bekannt, so dass man besser von *Rautenzeichen* und *Sternchen* sprechen sollte. (Offiziell heißt offiziell im Allgemeinen. Ich glaube man braucht keinen separaten Standard für Telefonie, sowie man auch keine separaten Wörter für diese Symbolen für Computer hat.)

*(Ich kenne eine Sekretärin, die statt Rautenzeichen Waffeleisen sagte; das versteht man doch auch! :-) )*

Comment: Ich kenn noch Gatter

Comment: @PortreeKid - Ja, das sagt man auf Niederländisch auch ("hekje")

Comment: Dass man in der Typographie von "Asterisk" spricht ist richtig, aber hier irrelavent. Die ITU sagt (E161, Arrangement of digits, letters and symbols... ) * _will be known as the star or the equivalent term in other languages_ und # _may be referred to as the square or the most commonly used equivalent term in other languages._ ... [A]n alternative term (e.g. "hash" or "number sign") may be necessary ... in which case it is useful ... to recommend a preferred term for consistent use nationally." Ich kennen keinen "recommended term" für Deutsch; auch und gerade nicht _Oktothorp_.

Comment: @user3723159 Never call it "`Oktothorp`", no one (maybe except linguists) will know what it means. `Raute`, `Doppelkreuz` or even `Hash` (if you're talking to technicans) are perfect. `Asterisk` might be well known; `Stern` or `Sternchen` is perfect.

Comment: Hast Du einen Beleg dafür, dass dies die offiziellen Namen sind?

Comment: Duden und Langenscheidt kennen "Oktothorp" nicht. **Äußerst** unwahrscheinlich, dass das der offizielle Name nach irgendeiner Norm ist.

Answer (score 4):

Ich kenne dafür die Namen:

- Raute
- Quadrat
- Nummernzeichen

und etwas abwegiger:

- Waffeleisen
- Lattenzaun
- Gartenzaun
- Kanalgitter

Für Aterisk gibt es bisher nur "Stern(chen)"

Answer (score 1):

There is no official name that I am aware of. Many people, myself included, call it Stern (or Sternchen, perhaps) and Raute. I have never heard either Oktothorp nor Asterisk in German.

Comment: Well, the Oktothorp and the Asterisk *are* the official names. It's not because you never hear them that they don't exist.

Comment: Possible, but I'm not prepared to take your word for it. Back it up, please.

Comment: http://www.dict.cc/?s=Asterisk. I can't find the Oktothorp right now, but you can easily find the English word *octothorpe* (which exists, though nobody knows it either)

Comment: Wikipedia, for what that's worth, states that "im Zusammenhang mit ... Telefonen findet sich oft trotz des nicht rautenförmigen Zeichens die Bezeichnung Raute, bei manchen großen Telefonnebenstellenanlagen die Bezeichnung Quadrat." I don't consider this official by any means, but at least it's consistent with my experience.

Comment: Of course it exists. I am just not convinced that it's the "official German name" used in this context (i.e. telephone and telecommunications).

Comment: Well, Asterisk is the official name for the star symbol. Does it need a separate official for phones?

Comment: "Official" how, exactly? It's one of several variants. That said, EOD for me.

Comment: @stevenvh: that's fine ... soon we will find it with ease in a quick Google-search (pointing to us as reference) ;)

Comment: @ingmar: if you doubt anything you don't know, but somebody else does, then you'll have a lot to doubt!

Comment: In the context of phone key pads, "Raute" and "Stern" are clearly the most commonly used words for these symbols.